# Looking for a good way to schedule MySQL updates from a Windows-based ODBC source

Tags: mysql

Am working with a propietary application that uses a dbisam database. We are looking to pipe scheduled updates from this source to a MySQL server (mostly likely on another box, but likely within the same datacenter). We have found and configured an ODBC driver that connects directly to the dbisam data.

Am looking for recommendations on a suggested tool/process/framework whereby we can either create a script, a service, or some compiled code that would trigger the connections and the updates on a schedule.

The originating side is definitely a Windows server box. The target side (and host of the MySQL) will most likely be Windows too, but it would be great if we had the option of it being a Linux server (not a requirement). Our desire is to use some PHP-based reporting tools against the MySQL data.

Would appreciate any feedback on how to do this.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a way to schedule a task. If so, *nix systems have `cron`, and Windows has the task scheduler. You can schedule whatever you want with either. How you perform the update is up to you. You can write a shell script; you can run an SQL script; you can use your application code... It just depends on what's the most convenient way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Lese, the scheduling part is easiest. Was hoping to get something more definitive in terms of an approach, toolkit, or product that we could follow..

Comment: I'm not sure it really matters. If you're already using ODBC, then it's probably just as well that you use an ODBC connection within the same app to sync the two DBs. Otherwise, maybe you could give more info on what the update process entails.